# How to find the last element in a list of the same images on a website using python and selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

How do i find the last element in dynamic list with images that all have the same id
is there a function that i can use like

driver.find_element_by_id('editwebsite').last()

in python, I want to select the last image in a table that have images with the same name

Comment: do you know what should be the number of the elements in the list?

Comment: No as this changes dynamically  as rows are added

Comment: Then there is no way to get the last one. If you do not know what element should be the last one, how would Selenium know that?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a function similar to last() on c# which finds the last element with the matching id

Comment: I have been able to find the number of the element by using the following

Comment: ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="editWebsite"]')
    print('length is', len(ids))

Comment: This will give you the number of elements which have been already "loaded" and added to DOM. Since your elements are being added dynamically this number might not be the final one and after you get the value new items could be loaded.

Comment: If you change your location strategy to xpath, it has a built-in function last(), which returns the last element in a matching results set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selenium method `driver.find_elements_by_id()` (note the plural form) returns a list of elements - even if there is a single one.
The idiomatic way of accessing list members is to use `[]` - `[0]` will return the 1st, `[1]` the 2nd, and so on; now, python also supports negative indices in the access - what they mean is "start from the back".

So for a list variable `lst`, accessing `lst[-1]` will get you the last element, `lst[-2]` the second to last, and so on.

In your particular case, this would be the usage:

```
driver.find_elements_by_id('editwebsite')[-1]
```

In languages that do not support negative indices, one would get the length of the list, and access the element at that position minus one (in most languages the list/arrays are zero based, e.g. the first element is at position 0). In python that would be:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_id('editwebsite')
size = len(elements)
target_element = elements[size -1]
```

, but in python that's not necessary (and some might consider it bad style, "unpythonic")

Comment: Thanks for all the help, this is the line of code i will use
 driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="editWebsite"]')[-1].click()

Answer (score 1):

At first find all the images with the id. Then select the last image from the list. In python that code would be:

```
def get_last_image():
    img_list = driver.find_elements_by_id('editwebsite')
    return img_list[len(img_list)-1]
```

*Note:* list starts from zero in python. So the last element of list will be at length-1.

**Important:** Since your images is loading dynamically, to get the last image you should call `get_last_image()` every time. By doing that you can get the last image from updated image list every time.

Comment: Don't use `list` for a variable name - that's a language keyword you now override, and can't access any more (`list()` is an object constructor, to return, well, lists :) )

Answer (score 0):

Find a commonality in all the elements... and Get all the elements using xpath.

```
List<WebElement> image_list = driver.findElements(...);
```

This returns a list of webElements. You can get the last elemement by

```
WebElement last_element = image_list.get(image_list.size());
```

Now you can take control of the last_element. 
This will also take care of the dynamically loaded images.
Hope this helps.

Comment: `image_list.get(image_list.size())` will fail with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. List indexing in Java ranges between 0 and `list.size() - 1`.